# Using clock() function to get tics in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, time.h

I trying to get the tics inside an [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) application using the C [clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/) function, but it updates very slowly. It looks like the thread in wich is running (is running inside a UIViewController) is inactive most of the time.
The difference between one measurement of the current tics and a subsequent one should be very high, but it change very little except when I'm constantly touching  the screen.

Is there a way to use this function and get good results in iOS?
Is there a similar library for iOS? I'm want to use it to create a timer for a game.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`clock()` measures cpu time used, not wall clock, could that be what you're seeing?

Comment: Yeah, by tics I actually mean CPU tics

Comment: @MauricioGalindo, what jthill means it that it gives you the CPU ticks for which your thread was active. For a thread that is just waiting for input this is expected behavior and a sign that everything goes smoothly.

Answer (score -2):

Why not try the `sleep` function?

```
sleep(X);
```

X is a number of milliseconds.

Comment: Getting the time is completely different to sleeping for a period of time!